# How to copy one branch with commit history to another new repo?

Tags: git, githooks, git-push

I would like to clone one branch from git repo A to new git repo B. Prefer to include all commits history.

Everything is OK following http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/. But when I try to push to remote, errors happened.

```
remote: ERROR: invalid comitter email: someone@hehe.com
...
remote: valid email addresses:
...
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/mybranch
To ssh://git@git.internal/myrepo.git
 ! [remote rejected] mybranch -> mybranch (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@git.internal/myrepo.git'
```

I know that all the past commits were done by another person, who is not in the list of valid email addresses any more. How to ignore this kind of verification? Is there any other way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Asked our admin to change the remote settings. Now everything works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should ignore the hooks:

```
git push --no-verify
```

from the [git-push documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> --[no-]verify
>   Toggle the pre-push hook (see githooks[5]). The default is --verify, giving the hook a chance to prevent the push. With --no-verify, the hook is bypassed completely.

**EDIT** as noted by @torek, the tag **[remote rejected]** indicates that the problem comes from the remote. So setting flags locally won't help. You need to look at the settings on your *git.internal* server.

Comment: git push --no-verify
error: unknown option `no-verify` Any idea why?

Comment: probably your git version is too old... what version do you have?

Comment: no, which git version number; use `git --version`. the option `--no-verify` was added in version 1.8.3.2.

Comment: if that is not possible, and if you are SURE that you won't destroy anything on the remote, you could try using `git push -f` which will force pushing, thus **CRUSHING** your remote branch...

Comment: not work. my Ubuntu is precise. Now, try to update git.

Comment: tried git push origin mybranch --no-verify, still the same problem hook declined

Comment: then try my second solution; if there is nothing important on the remote branch; then you can use `git push -f`, which will **crush** your remote branch... try also in combination with --no-verify.

Comment: tried -f too. not work. Now I need to make sure whether there are some custom settings in our git repos... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any message prefixed with `remote:` like that is coming from the *other* git, the one receiving your push.  Telling your own git to skip your own hooks won't help, as it's not your own git complaining, it's the remote one.

Comment: @BAE: The `-f` (force) flag is the only built-in client-side request, and it's not passed to the server-side hooks anyway, so when the error comes from a remote hook, you must consult the remote hook itself to find out how to bypass it, if this bypass is even possible.  In other words, you must look to your `git.internal` site.